# Need to prove time complexity of right-to-left binary method for modular exponentiation

Tags: algorithm

I have used [Right-to-Left Method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation#Right-to-left_binary_method) to implement an algorithm for modular exponentiation but my professor says that the its time complexity can't be O(log exponent) and that wikipedia is not a trusted source.

Anyway I checked the source where the pseudocode was taken from but it does not state a time complexity. Can anyone help me find a valid academic source for this?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: the code is the exact version of the pseudocode shown on the wikipedia page

Answer (score 2):

You don't need an academic source for something that you can safely derive yourself.

When you perform modular exponentiation using right-to-left method, you start with two `n`-digit numbers, `b` and `m`, and a `k`-bit exponent `e`.

```
modular_pow(b, m, e)
    if m = 1 {
        return 0
    }
    res = 1
    b = b mod m
    while e != 0
        if e mod 2 == 1 {
           res := (res * b) mod m
        }
        e >>= 1
        b = (b * b) mod m
    return res
```

You perform `k` bit shifts of the exponent `e`before the loop stops, which is equivalent to performing log<sub>2</sub>e divisions by 2. Each step of the loop performs one or two multiplications, and one or two mod operations. This leads to the overall time complexity of O(k*M(n)), where M(n) is time complexity of your multiplication algorithm.

> Professor says that the its time complexity can't be O(log exponent)

Time complexity could be O(log exponent) under a specific condition - time complexity of M(n) is O(1). This holds true for primitive numbers on most modern CPUs.

Most likely, your professor was talking about a more interesting case - namely, when `b` and `m` are `n`-digit numbers, where `n` does not have a practical upper limit.

[This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_complexity_of_mathematical_operations) lists possible time complexities for M(n), depending on the multiplication algorithm. The complexity ranges from O(n<sup>2</sup>) for the schoolbook long multiplication to O(n * log n * 2<sup>O(log* n)</sup>) for Fürer's algorithm.

Comment: You suggest that the algorithm is no longer in O(log(exponent)) for b,m of arbitrary length just in the practical implementation, right? Or is there something I am missing?

Comment: @thcpx Any implementation of this algorithm needs O(1) multiplication in order to be O(log(exponent)). Since we have a lot of choices in picking our multiplication algorithm, the right approach is to express the complexity of this algorithm in terms of complexity of the multiplication algorithm that we use, i.e. M(n). Note if `n` has a fixed upper limit (say, no more than 1000 digits) it is fair to claim that the algorithm is O(log(exponent)) again, because even with the slowest multiplication algorithm of O(n*n) we have O(1000000 * log(exponent)), which is O(log(exponent))).